# Passing Exception Message to Queue::failing() in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: laravel, queue, laravel-5.1, ironmq

Using Laravel 5.1's Queues, I'm throwing an exception when a job fails.

```
throw new \Exception('No luck');
```

As Laravel recommends when [dealing with failed jobs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#dealing-with-failed-jobs), I'm "catching" the exception in the `AppServiceProvider`, and using that to send our team an email.

```
public function boot()
{
    Queue::failing(function ($connection, $job, $data) {
        $info['data'] = $data;
        \Mail::send('emails.jobs.failed', $info, function($message) {
            $message->to('test@email.com')->subject('Job failed');
        });
    });
}
```

Within the email, I would like to place the exception's message (in this case "No luck.").  But I can't figure out how to pass that along to Queue::failing().

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

After calling the failing callback, [Laravel rethrows the exception](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/648add30883ccd91f5080bb231d8394bf39ba30f/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php#L221).

It seems if you really need the error message, you'll have to catch the exception yourself.

Comment: Thanks Joseph.  I'm really trying to figure out a why to let our team know why a job failed in the first place.  Right now, were only being notified that a specific job fails, with no details why.  Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: @MartyThomas - I'm not sure what you're asking. Like I said in the answer, you can catch the exception and send the email there.

Comment: @MartyThomas - the reason you're running into this is because the failures were never meant to be used the way you are. A queue job shouldn't use exceptions to control app flow. If for whatever reason you couldn't execute the job, you should handle that within the job's handler. The `failing` callback is meant for unexpected failures (the exception is still logged to the main app log file).

Comment: I was using the exception in the question, because I thought that was a good way to demonstrate what I was trying to do, but that's obviously not working too well :)  I was having trouble debugging why jobs were failing (unexpectedly), and I thought that the `failing` callback would be the solution.  But maybe I'm thinking about this in the wrong way. Thanks again for the thoughts.

Comment: It is [still the case](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/3adc11fa6a41591d267cab5bf0c3ea2d388f3185/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php#L378) after like 4 years. Seems the correct way btw.